# Invoking GCC as "cc" versus "gcc"

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-construction, gnu

I am aware that on most GNU/Linux systems, GCC can be invoked by the name "cc" from the command line (as opposed to "gcc"). Is there any difference in GCC's behavior when it is invoked one way versus the other?

For example, I know that invoking GCC through the name "g++" instead of "gcc" causes GCC to behave differently (it treats .c files as C++ source and links-in the C++ standard library). Is there any similar difference in behavior between "gcc" versus "cc"?

**EDIT:** None of the answers received so far gave a *definitive* "yes" or "no" as to whether GCC will behave differently if invoked one way versus the other. However, the idea given to dive into the source to check its behavior lead me down that path. Based upon what I found there, I now believe that the answer is:

**No. GCC behaves the same regardless of whether it is called via "gcc" or "cc"**.

Comment: Seems to be the same aa gawk vs awk, gmake vs make etc. I would sell me on them being equal always. On solaris systems, I hear that make is different from gmake (gnu make). Perhaps on some system similar things apply for gcc vs cc.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For grins, I just traced down how `argv[0]` is used from within gcc ([`main.c`](http://www.koders.com/c/fidF9A47C3300302CAAE31390DBB8C872977D7CD222.aspx?s=cdef%3atree) -> `top_lev.c` -> `opts.c` -> `langhooks.c`) and it appears that `argv[0]` is currently used for nothing more than giving `malloc` something to report when it fails.  There doesn't appear to be any behavior change if `argv[0]` is anything other than `gcc`.

Comment: The only problem that I have with that is that "cc --version" gives *slightly* different output from "gcc --version" (it says "cc" instead of "gcc"). So *something* in there must be looking at argv[0].

Comment: Your answer motivated me to look into the source code myself. I found that argv[0] does get assigned to "programname" which ends up getting passed around a bit to other functions (and gets stored in the environment). Although I didn't do an *exhaustive* search, from what I can see, it is only ever used for display purposes (e.g. in the "--version" output, "usage" output, error messages, etc).

Comment: I just came to notice that this is true only if cc and gcc are the same executable. May it happen that the system has different binaries? Imaginr that cc may link to a clang binary and gcc to gcc. Honest question, I have no idea.

Answer (score 15):

It looks to me that [`cc`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/cc.html) (link to some old SUS specification) is intended to be the vendor-neutral interface to the system's compiler. It's marked as legacy:

> The c89 utility provides an interface to the ISO C standard, but the cc utility accepts an unspecified dialect of the C language: it may be Standard C, common-usage C or some other variant. Portable C programs should be written to conform to the ISO C standard and compiled with c89.

POSIX has a utility called [`c99`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/c99.html) which I believe is the successor of `c89`. It says

> The c99 utility is based on the c89 utility originally introduced in the ISO POSIX-2:1993 standard.
>   Some of the changes from c89 include the modification to the contents of the Standard Libraries section to account for new headers and options; for example,  added to the -l rt operand, and the -l trace operand added for the Tracing functions.

I'm not really familiar to all those different standards, but it looks like the more recent SUSv3 ([POSIX:2004](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX:2004)) and the yet more recent [POSIX:2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX:2008) (doesn't seem to have a SUS number yet) do not specify a utility called `cc` anymore, but only the utility called `c99`. Incidentally, my Linux system ([Arch_Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux)) contains a manpage of `c99` but not `c89`, but only contains a utility called `cc`, but neither `c89` nor `c99`. Much confusion in there :)

Comment: Interesting link. Someone should probably tell the GNU Make people about this, because it will still invoke "cc" as the default if you don't override ${CC}. Apparently they should be using one of the other utilities as a default. It would seem that c89 *should* be the preferred utility according to the standard.

Comment: OTOH, since that was written in 1997, maybe these days the preferred utility ought to be c99.

Comment: yes, SUSv3 doesn't include c89 anymore. only the old one i linked to recommended it (SUSv2)

Answer (score 12):

On my mac from `man gcc`:

> In Apple's version of GCC, both cc and
>   gcc are actually symbolic links to a
>   compiler named like gcc-version.
>   Similarly, c++ and g++ are links to a
>   compiler named like g++-version.

Based on that I would assume that cc and gcc behave the same way.

Comment: it's common on Unix world to set several links to the same executable, and it changes some defaults according to the name it was used when called.

Comment: woah and a downvote without explanation - very helpful ... maybe they didn't like something?

Comment: Maybe they don't know that Mac OS X is fully posix compliant Unix system

Comment: No, perhaps they consider confusing the following logical chain: "symlinked to the same executable -> same behavior". For instance all your basic command line utils can be symlinked to busybox on minimal system, yet function as entirely separate utils

Answer (score 11):

I had the same doubt today and I tried to find it on my own:

`which` - Determine executable location

`file` - Determine file type

```
$ which cc
 /usr/bin/cc

$file /usr/bin/cc
 /usr/bin/cc: symbolic link to '/etc/alternatives/cc'

$file /etc/alternatives/cc
 /etc/alternatives/cc: symbolic link to '/usr/bin/gcc'

$which gcc
 /usr/bin/gcc
```

So, basically `cc` points to `gcc`.

You could also check using `cc -v` and `gcc -v`. If they print out the same thing, that means they are exactly the same.

Comment: Note the comment that Javier gave to stefanB's answer, though -- Unix provides the "name of the program" to a program as the 0th command-line argument, and many programs in Unix are set up with symbolic links from many different names and change their behavior depending on which name was used to call them.  (For instance, gunzip is a link to gzip, but if you call gzip it compresses things and if you call gunzip it uncompresses them.)  Thus, it's entirely plausible that GCC might act differently if you run it via a symlink named 'cc'.

Answer (score 7):

Even if gcc operates the same independent of argv[0]'s value, not all software will operate the same regardless of which you specify as the compiler.

When building zlib 1.2.5 on RHEL 5.5 (gcc 4.1.2):

```
$ md5sum $(which cc)
69a67d3029b8ad50d41abab8d778e799  /usr/bin/cc
$ md5sum $(which gcc)
69a67d3029b8ad50d41abab8d778e799  /usr/bin/gcc
```

But:

```
$ CC=$(which cc) ./configure
Checking for shared library support...
Tested /usr/bin/cc -w -c -O ztest20557.c
Tested cc -shared -O -o ztest20557.so ztest20557.o
/usr/bin/ld: ztest20557.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
ztest20557.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
No shared library support; try without defining CC and CFLAGS
Building static library libz.a version 1.2.5 with /usr/bin/cc.
Checking for off64_t... Yes.
Checking for fseeko... Yes.
Checking for unistd.h... Yes.
Checking whether to use vs[n]printf() or s[n]printf()... using vs[n]printf().
Checking for vsnprintf() in stdio.h... Yes.
Checking for return value of vsnprintf()... Yes.
```

And:

```
$ CC=$(which gcc) ./configure
Checking for shared library support...
Building shared library libz.so.1.2.5 with /usr/bin/gcc.
Checking for off64_t... Yes.
Checking for fseeko... Yes.
Checking for unistd.h... Yes.
Checking whether to use vs[n]printf() or s[n]printf()... using vs[n]printf().
Checking for vsnprintf() in stdio.h... Yes.
Checking for return value of vsnprintf()... Yes.
Checking for attribute(visibility) support... Yes.
```

The configure script does not consider the possibility that cc on a Linux system could be gcc. So, be careful how far you take your assumptions.

Comment: This goes without saying. The compiler isn't behaving any differently. This is a shortcoming of the `configure` script. The script knows that `gcc` can generate shared libraries and it knows that `gcc` needs the `-fPIC` option when compiling shared libraries on Linux. If the compiler is not `gcc`, then `configure` attempts to test whether the compiler can generate shared libraries. **But** it cannot divine what compiler flags are needed for a compiler that it does not know, so you the user must supply them. You need to supply the necessary flags on the command line (e.g. via `CFLAGS=-fPIC`).

Comment: This was intended as an auxiliary caution rather than an answer. Invoking gcc as cc in the above case would not cause it to operate differently, but the invoking software operated in a nonintuitive manner that caused the appearance of different behavior.

Answer (score 3):

cc is just the UNIX way of calling the compiler, it will work on all Unices.

Comment: This does not address the question.

Comment: Actually it does, cc means "C compiler" on Unix, nothing more.

Comment: The questioner asked about the difference of cc and gcc too. This serves as an answer too and addresses the question, imo

Answer (score 3):

this thread might be old but I want to add something to it
(maybe someone will find it in the future).

If you compiled this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void
myFunction(char *args)
{
   char buff1[12];
   char buff2[4] = "ABC";

   strcpy(buff1,args);

   printf("Inhalt Buffer2: %s",buff2);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   if(argc > 1)
   {
      myFunction(argv[1]);
   }
   else
      printf("no arguments sir daimler benz");

   getchar();

   return 0;
}
```

with "gcc", and you pass it "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" as argument, it will not overflow into buffer2, while it DOES if you compiled with "cc", which for me is a hint that if you used "gcc", the memory management works different, maybe by putting space between the memory segments of the fields buff1 & buff2 ?

Maybe someone with more experiance can put light into the darkness here.

Comment: I tried this (on gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)), with stack protector off and on and both end with either **segmentation fault** or **stack smashing detected**, in the end cc is link to /etc/alternatives/cc and that is link to /usr/bin/gcc. As @abcoep says cc and gcc differs only with tab completion (as far as I could investigate).

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the GCC documentation indicates that GCC would behave any differently if its executable name is not *gcc* but *cc*. The GNU Fortran compiler even [mentions that](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gfortran/Getting-Started.html):

> A version of the gcc command (which also might be installed as the system's cc command)

Answer (score 2):

> "No. GCC behaves the same regardless of whether it is called via 'gcc'
> or 'cc'."
>
> [Quoted from original post.]

Based on my experienced in Ubuntu 14.04, this hasn't been the case.

When I compile my program using:

```
gcc -finstrument-functions test.c
```

I don't get any change in the behavior of my code. But when I compile using

```
cc -finstrument-functions test.c
```

It does behave differently. (In both cases, I incorporated the appropriate changes into my code described [here](http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2010/09/gcc-function-instrumentation.html) to make -finstrument-functions work).

Answer (score 1):

Considering this is coming from UNIX, I'd say that "cc" is the generic name and "gcc" is the actual compiler. i.e. "gcc" provides "cc" so a program looking for "cc" would find and use "cc", blissfully ignorant of the actual compiler being used.

Also, UNIX programs should be ignorant of the actual name used to call them (think Windows Desktop shortcuts -- it doesn't make sense to check what the shortcut was called), so, no, "gcc" and "cc" do the same thing if "cc" is a link to "gcc".

Unless, of course, "cc" is not a symlink but a shellscript calling gcc.

Comment: gzip checks its name. If its name is gunzip it assumes -d.

Comment: "Also, UNIX programs should be ignorant of the actual name used to call them" It's absolutely not true. Have you ever heard of multi-call binaries? I.e. Busybox? http://www.busybox.net/

Comment: and, after all, "sh" is usually a symlink to "bash", which makes it behave as a POSIX shell. sh<->bash is actually very similar to cc<->gcc .

Comment: Well, gzip<->gunzip is a case of the same utility providing two different utilities. In the case of gcc<->cc it's providing one thing.

I did make a generalisation about unix tools being argv[0] agnostic, but for the most part they are, simply because otherwise they'd break if renamed. If one binary provides more than one utility, then, yes, there's a difference between calling it directly and calling the symlink it creates to provide the tool in question, but gcc<->cc is not that: unless the semantics (i.e. expected behaviour) change, they're synonyms for historical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

For my OS (Ubuntu 14.04) `cc` doesn't allow tab completion, whereas `gcc` does.